# Matlab multiplied iterator for array index inside parfor - slicing

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, iterator, parfor

Is it possible to slice 3'rd line (tt)? This code is simplified, but the problem is similar. I am using multiplied iterator (3*i) in array index, however it doesn't work. Maybe it is possible to change it somehow.

```
parfor i = 1 : NE      
   tmp = i * [1, -1; -1, 1];                 
   tt(3*i-1:3*i+1) = tmp([3,2,4]);          
   pp(i) = tmp(1,1,i);   
end;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. This code doesn't work as a simple `for` loop because in line 4 you're trying to access a 3rd dimension of `tmp`, but `tmp` is just a 2x2 matrix. Can you fix the code to work in a standard `for` loop? Then maybe we can see what you're trying to do and help with the `parfor`.

Comment: Sorry, that was 'making function easier' mistake. :) It should be pp() = tmp(i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be a [sliced output variable](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/advanced-topics.html#bq_of7_-1), `tt` must be indexed using literally only the loop variable `i`, and other constant terms (including `:`). Perhaps you can make `tt` rectangular, and assign a whole column at a time, and then reshape later, something like this:

```
tt = zeros(3, 10);  
parfor ii = 1:10
  tt(:, ii) = [ii; ii; ii];
end
tt = reshape(tt, 1, numel(tt));
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked out. But, still, it is strange, that it is not possible to multiply iterator in index.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's one of the restrictions of PARFOR - for it to know how to slice your data, you must use the loop variable directly.